# Adding numbers from in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string that says:

calculation = "10+3-2"
print(calculation) # This should equal 11

I can't figure out a way the string so Python would do the math. I have tried splitting the string etc but nothing worked.
Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `eval()` function:

```
calculation = eval("10+3-2")

print(calculation)
```

or

```
calculation = "10+3-2"

print(eval(calculation))
```